# Format Date String in momentjs

Tags: date, momentjs

I am trying to format a timezone based

How can i convert a JS time into these formats?

> "Thu Sep 24 2015 14:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
>
> "September 24th 2015, 2:00:00 pm UTC-07:00"
>
> "2015-09-24 14:00:00 GMT-0700"
>
> "Sept 24 2015 14:00:00 GMT-0700"
>
> "Thu Sep 24 2015 14:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"

Converting into any of it would help.

Comment: Have you tried by your-self? Can you post some of your code to see what you are missing or if there is some error?

Comment: I was able to get the 3rd one using this format:

`"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss zZZ"`

Comment: Ok, can you post your code, please? It would be very useful to start from what you tried...

Comment: ```var time = "2016-11-09 15:38:00",
      zone = "America/Chicago",
      format = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss zZZ";```

`moment.tz(time,zone).utc().format(format)`

Comment: Ok, but you asked "Converting into any of it would help." but you are able to convert in the 3rd one... It answers your own question. Am I correct?

Comment: i was able to make one, but it would be better for future case if someone tries to convert it in the given format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tokens listed in the [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) documentation, as shown in the following snippet.

Use square brackets `[]` to add characters that should be escaped (`GMT` and `UTC` in the example, if you need current zone abbreviation use the `z` token).

Note that as the [moment-timezone docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/) says:

> Moment.js also provides a hook for the long form time zone name. Because these strings are generally localized, Moment Timezone does not provide any long names for zones.
>
> To provide long form names, you can override `moment.fn.zoneName` and use the `zz` token.

You can find in the snippet an example of providing long names for zones.

```js
var time = "2016-11-09 15:38:00", zone = "America/Chicago";

var m = moment.tz(time,zone);

console.log(m.format('ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ (z)'));
console.log(m.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a [UTC]ZZ'));
console.log(m.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ'));
console.log(m.format('MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ'));

// Add long names for sample zones
var abbrs = {
    EST : 'Eastern Standard Time',
    EDT : 'Eastern Daylight Time',
    CST : 'Central Standard Time',
    CDT : 'Central Daylight Time',
    MST : 'Mountain Standard Time',
    MDT : 'Mountain Daylight Time',
    PST : 'Pacific Standard Time',
    PDT : 'Pacific Daylight Time',
};

moment.fn.zoneName = function () {
    var abbr = this.zoneAbbr();
    return abbrs[abbr] || abbr;
};

console.log(m.format('ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ (zz)'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.7/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make third one using this snippet

```
var time = "2016-11-09 15:38:00", 
    zone = "America/Chicago", 
    format = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss zZZ"; 

moment.tz(time,zone).utc().format(format)
```